How to setSelection on a Google Sankey Chart opening
I use Google Charts Sankey and I need to set a node selected when displaying the chart.
I'm able to get the selected node when I click on the node, with the following listener :
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function() {
    var sel = chart.getSelection();
    if (sel.length) {
      alert('clicked item : '+JSON.stringify(sel));
    }
  });

But the corresponding listener called when the chart is rendered does not work :
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function() {
    var sel = [{"name":"A"}];
    chart.setSelection(sel);
  });

I tried to change the content of the "sel" parameter (including row and column parameters as mentionned in the Google API documentation) but wihtout any effect.
A jsfiddle is available here : https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/yo5f4ng7
I would like the "A node" selected by default on open.
